# WordPress API causing fatal error

Tags: api

I can't seem to figure out why my API call is failing when trying to filter the fields using `_fields`.

It seems to work all but one of the fields, when I add it, it dies with

> "There has been a critical error on this website."

I've checked the error log and the error is

> Uncaught Error: Class name must be a valid object or a string

Here is the stack trace...

#0 /wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-controller.php(434): SP_REST_API::get_post_data(Array, 'data', Object(WP_REST_Request), 'sp_table')

#1 /wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php(1833): WP_REST_Controller->add_additional_fields_to_object(Array, Object(WP_REST_Request))

#2 /wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php(327): WP_REST_Posts_Controller->prepare_item_for_response(Object(WP_Post), Object(WP_REST_Request))

#3 /wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php(1139): WP_REST_Posts_Controller->get_items(Object(WP_REST_Request))

#4 /wp-includes/rest-api/class in /wp-content/plugins/sportspress-pro/includes/sportspress/includes/api/class-sp-rest-api.php on line 764

What I've noticed is that this particular field is an object containing a number of objects, where as the others that retrieve successfully are arrays.

How can I filter for the object field?

Comment: Can you find us the actual PHP error from the server error log please? (or PHP error log if different, or the WordPress debug.log if enabled.) And enough of a stack trace for context.

Comment: I checked the logs, it has quite a long stack trace, but this is the error

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class name must be a valid object or a string

Comment: Great. Could you edit that into the question please with a few lines of stack trace? Or the ones that look relevant to the filter at least. (The error message itself isn't that useful without knowing where it happened.) Which version of WordPress are you running, 5.8?

Comment: Done :) I didn't mention that if I don't filter the fields at all, it works

Comment: OK, it looks like you're running 5.7 or 5.7.1. The line is "$prepared[ $field_name ] = call_user_func( $field_options['get_callback'], $prepared, $field_name, $request, $this->get_object_type() );" so I'm guessing that $field_options['get_callback'] is wrong - I can't see what else there would cause that error. So you'd need to work out what the value of $field_options['get_callback'] is here, e.g. trace it out using error_log(), or look at class-sp-rest-api.php to see how it has set up the additional fields property.

Comment: However since this is a SportsPress Pro API endpoint I'd ask them directly if you haven't already, since it looks like this is one of their endpoints and I'd guess the callback function is theirs too.

Comment: Confirmed as a bug in the SportsPress 2.7.8 API, thanks for pointing me in the right direction @Rup